# Change an element's css class that resides outside a loop from inside a loop

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
$count = 1;
$featuredPosts = 9;
query_posts('showposts=19');
?>

<div class="articleTile column_3">

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if($count > $featuredPosts) : ?> 

        <!--change class to articleList column_2-->

    <?php endif; ?>

<div class="column">

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'featured' ); ?>

    <!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

</div>

<?php
$count = $count ++;
endwhile;
?>

</div>
```

How would I go about targeting the `<div class="articleTile column_3">` element and changing its class when the count variable reaches 10?

EDIT: I'm an idiot sorry.

I've managed to do it with:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
$count = 1;
$featuredPosts = 9;
query_posts('showposts=19');
?>

<div class="articleTile column_3">

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if($count == $featuredPosts + 1) : ?>

    <?php echo $count ?>
        </div>
        <div class="articleList column_2">

    <?php endif; ?>

<div class="column">
<?php echo $count ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'featured' ); ?>

    <!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

</div>

<?php
$count = $count +1;
endwhile;
?>

</div>
```

My original way wouldn't have worked anyway without a 2nd element with a different class. My apologies. Thanks for the fast responses they helped point me in the right direction.

Comment: You will have to catch the output of the loop in a variable, and echo the container and content afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it smarter to just run the a loop first to check what the total count is gonna be and then use it to set the right class?

Something like this perhaps? :

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
$count = 1;
$count_posts = 1;
$featuredPosts = 9;
$class = 'column_3';

query_posts('showposts=19');

/* Run loop */
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

    $count_posts = $count_posts ++;
endwhile;

if ($count_posts > $featuredPosts) { $class = 'column_2'; }

?>

<div class="articleTile <? echo $class; ?>">

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>



<div class="column">

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'featured' ); ?>

    <!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

</div>

<?php
$count = $count ++;
endwhile;
?>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I was being daft. I've ammeneded the original question with the resolution. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a condition in the div class like

you need to place this div inside a loop

```
<div class="<?php echo ($count<=10) ? 'articleTile column_3' : 'articleTile column_5' ?>">
```

Comment: You're missing the point: `$count` will always be 1 at that point as it's incremented only in the loop *after* the div is already printed.

Comment: @Juhana, spot on! That's exactly my problem. I need to change the class while the loop is running.

Comment: I mean it should come inside a loop, but didn't mentioned it since always $count and increments can happen inside a loop

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
$count = 1;
$featuredPosts = 9;
query_posts('showposts=19');
?>

<div class="articleTile column_3">

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if($count == $featuredPosts + 1) : ?>

    <?php echo $count ?>
        </div>
        <div class="articleList column_2">

    <?php endif; ?>

<div class="column">
<?php echo $count ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'featured' ); ?>

    <!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

</div>

<?php
$count = $count +1;
endwhile;
?>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class=<?php echo $class; ?></div>
```

You can try this on the element that you want to change class.

```
$class = "oldclass";
if(a==10){
$class= "newclass";
}
```

Comment: Again, if you read the question carefully the problem is that the OP knows the total count only *after* the class has already been printed.

Comment: Yeah, i know. What I am telling is that, he can use that technique to change the div's class.